# getElementById() breaking loop

Tags: javascript

I Have a problem... Here's the deal. I have a lot of elements and a button to hide them all, looks like

Category1 (for example id="1")
  - line1 (for example thats div, id="1-1" class="**blue**")
  - line2 (for example thats div, id="1-2" class="**blue**")
  - line3 (for example thats div, id="1-3" class="red")
  - line4 (for example thats div, id="1-4" class="green")

Etc. Lines have different classes, and that's a long story. Thing is I need to hide "Category1" caption (div) if there is no visible elements. And that's ok.
But Also i need to show it when any line of that category appears again...

So i have this 
( idl = line class (associative massive, contains blue,red,green,etc), by custom function getElementsByClassName()... And this is "show line" function

```
   for (i=0;i<idl.length;i++) 
   {
   idl[i].style.display = "block";
   cla = idl[i].id; 
   if (cla[1]='-') {cla = cla[0];}
   else {cla = cla[0] + cla[1];}     //weird way to get Category id but works
                                     //just cut off "-1" "-2" part of line IDs
                                     // loop is doing it's job.

   /* if ( getElementById(cla) || getElementById(cla).style.display!="block" ) {
      getElementById(cla).style.display = "block";
      } 
   */

    // now here if I use 3 lines above it stops. 1st loop and that's it.
    // even after getElementById("12345"), after getElementById(everything here)
    // and nothing happening if i put alert anything after
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's "stopping" that means there's an error. You should always have the JavaScript console (or Firebug or some other debugger tool) open while testing JavaScript or else you'll waste a *lot* of time.

Comment: With jquery, it'd be simple. `$('#1').children().hide();`

Comment: Also, Id should not begin with number.

Comment: okay, no numbers at beginning, but still, it breaks after any getElementById()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getElementById` in the global scope, [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) is a method on `document` so you're trying to call an undefined value as a function and failing. You want something more like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById(cla);
if(el && el.style.display != 'block')
    el.style.display = 'block';
```

Also note that the logic has been fixed to use `&&` rather than `||`.

Comment: Yep, my bad. But it still breaks at el = document.getElementById(cla); (1st line) because of something

Comment: @Ярослав: What does "breaks" mean? Anything in the error console? Are you sure that `cla` is correct? Have you tried prefixing your `id` attributes with something that isn't a number?